# install introduction package in TYPO3 11 with composer

Tags: installation, composer-php, typo3, typo3-11.x, typo3-console

TYPO3 11 LTS with composer.

I tried:

- composer require typo3/cms-introduction

the introduction package and bootstrap package are loaded.

Then i tried:

- vendor/bin/typo3 extension:setup

but nothing happens. In the extensions manager i can see both extensions but no page in the page tree, nothing in the backend.

There are different descriptions out in the world:

- composer exec typo3 extension:setup

results in this error message:

Script typo3 handling the __exec_command event returned with error code 255

It seems impossible to install the introduction package in TYPO3 11 with composer.

Any hints?

Thanks
Peter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use always

```
vendor/bin/typo3cms install:setup
vendor/bin/typo3cms install:extensionsetupifpossible
```

and never had any problems, it requires this though:

```
"helhum/typo3-console": "^7.0.2"
```

I tested it with the introduction package too and the pages are created. The frontend is directly shown correctly after this.
My setup was completely based on composer, so there is no general problem to install the introduction package by composer.

If you want to repair the installation, keep care about the hint in the installation instruction:

> If you want to re-install ext:introduction on an instance that had ext:introduction
> loaded before, the data import is only performed if you (manually) remove the keys
> marked with `extensionDataImport` in column `entry_namespace` from database table
> `sys_registry` that are related to the introduction paths.
> Note it is often easier to just install TYPO3 from scratch if you just want to play around.

**TYPO3 and composer**
Documentation related to composer is included in several documents:

- [TYPO3 installation](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/tutorial-getting-started/11.5/en-us/Installation/Install.html)
  There exist two distributions that can be installed:
- [minmal](https://packagist.org/packages/typo3/minimal) is a very slim collection of system extensions.
- [base-distribution](https://packagist.org/packages/typo3/cms-base-distribution) is a collection with most of the common system extensions.
- naturally it's also possible to start with an individual composer.json file that is defining an own set of system extensions, so the packages above wouldn't be used.
  It's also possible to install just an extension by composer without having installed TYPO3 before, then TYPO3 gets automatically installed as dependency if the extension defines at least one system extension as dependency.
- [Minor TYPO3 upgrade](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/guide-installation/main/en-us/Minor/Index.html)
- [Major TYPO3 upgrade](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/guide-installation/main/en-us/Major/UpgradeCore.html)
- [Explanation of composer.json for TYPO3](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/ExtensionArchitecture/FileStructure/ComposerJson.html)

Furthermore there is an online helper for composer that makes it easier to collect all the desired packages for commandline:
https://get.typo3.org/misc/composer/helper
Note that it's not always better to install more packages and that not every package is available for every TYPO3 version.

**typo3-console**
The manual for the typo3-console can be found here:
https://docs.typo3.org/p/helhum/typo3-console/7.1/en-us/
You can switch the version in the top left corner of the manual.
The typo3-console can be used for non-composer installations too, it can be downloaded here:

- https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/typo3_console
- https://github.com/TYPO3-Console/TYPO3-Console/tags

**TYPO3 v12**
For TYPO3 v12 the typo3-console is not compatible yet (Oct. 7, 2022), so some steps in the install-process have to be done manually and are not available yet by command line.
All composer commands can be used and are not concerned by the missing console. Just in `composer.json` files usually this block is used and has to be removed until typo3-console is compatibel to v12:

```
    "scripts":{
        "typo3-cms-scripts": [
            "typo3cms install:fixfolderstructure"
        ],
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "@typo3-cms-scripts"
        ]
    },
```

Comment: Hi David, thanks! vendor/bin/typo3cms install:extensionsetupifpossible works.

Comment: BTW; I use composer combined with ddev a lot for local development

Comment: Good tip, thx, Looks like missing doc.

Comment: @biesior I added some text, let me know if you're still missing something!

Comment: @David I didn't mean you when saying about missing doc, sorry for misunderstanding, ;) Rather referred to luck of clear explanation in official TYPO3 docs (or I missed something ;p). Thanks for your effort, and v12 tip, just downgraded my newest project to v11.5 this morning cause of this, but will check it out and will back to falling in love in newest TYPO3 as it gives a lot of power. I only regret I can't upvote your answer even more :D

Comment: Thanks a lot @biesior. I understood you quite well and hoped you found the desired info in the linked docs perhaps ;-)